# Data info: Orange data mining

Tags: data-mining, orange

I am trying to use the widgets from Orange Data Mining in the practical world. When do you use Data Info in Orange Data Mining set?

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on getting your hands dirty with some real data science!
Data Info does what is says: provides general information on the data set. When do you use it? Well, when you wish to know basic attributes of your data. Also, please refer to the [documentation](https://orangedatamining.com/widget-catalog/) to see how/when to use each widget.